# How i can know the Screen resolution in VB-2010?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I need to know how i can know the Screen resolution within vb-2010, show the Screen resolution  in "TextBox" for example.
And know the account name, if i can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
Dim screenWidth as Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
Dim screenHeight as Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
```

Read more from this, excellent [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122691/getting-screen-resolution) from [Cody Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray)