# Get Screen resolution

Tags: vb.net, resolution

Is there any implemented code to get screen resolution?

I want to make a program which will work different for different screen resolutions.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the following, its already built into the Framework.

```
 Dim screenWidth as Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
 Dim screenHeight as Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
```

Note that before asking, research. This has been answered already and was found with a quick Google Search - [Getting Screen Resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122691/getting-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

My solution will work also for extended desktops (dual-screen)

```
''' <summary>
''' Gets the extended screen resolution (for Dual-Screens).
''' </summary>
Private Function GetExtendedScreenResolution() As Point

    Dim ResX As Integer = 
        (From scr As Screen In Screen.AllScreens Select scr.Bounds.Width).Sum

    Dim ResY As Integer = 
        (From scr As Screen In Screen.AllScreens Select scr.Bounds.Height).Sum

    Return New Point(ResX, ResY)

End Function

''' <summary>
''' Gets the primary screen resolution.
''' </summary>
Private Function GetPrimaryScreenResolution() As Point

    Return New Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)

End Function
```

Usage Examples:

```
' Usage Examples:
MsgBox(GetExtendedScreenResolution.ToString)
Dim Resolution as Point = GetExtendedScreenResolution()
Me.Size = GetPrimaryScreenResolution()
```