# How to automatically re-size controls based on screen resolution in C#?

Tags: c#

this is different question from last one. in that question I asked how to fit bigger form in different screen and the answer were helpful but did not solve the issue.

[How do I fit/re-size Windows Form to any screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434486/how-do-i-fit-re-size-windows-form-to-any-screen-resolution)

I developed an application using windows forms C# under screen resolution `1366x778` and when I run my application in different screen size (different resolution) it missed some parts because the form appeared too big for the screen.

I partly solved this issued using Anchor / Docks and made the form to maximize but now the new problem is: the controls which on the form do not re-size themselves to fit the screen and they overlap each other instead.

My question is: is there any equation/function or any idea to make all the controls in the Form to re-size themselves according to the screen resolution? something like for example: lets say `form1` has `button1` and size of `button1` is `100x100` and the new screen resolution is `1280x960`, can we re-size `button1` based on the resolution?

Please help . Thank you.

Comment: @ Sinatr. this is different question. in that question I asked how to re-size the whole form to fit the screen and i solved it, now i asked how can I re-size controls!

Comment: It is the exact same question.  The detail you somehow missed is that the screen size is completely irrelevant.  You must make your UI work when the *window* is resized.  So be sure to give it a resizable border and don't stop until it works acceptably whenever you drag the window corner.  Cop-outs are MinimumSize so you don't have to make it work for a postage stamp and AutoScroll so you can convince the user to buy a bigger monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, you have to use Anchor and Dock, read this tutorial that explains how to resize winform and controls:

> http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908/