# How to get the width of the screen in asp.net with VB

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I want to get the width of the screen without the user pressing a button etc.

I first found the following question

[Screen width stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122691/getting-screen-resolution)

So i tried that and my code is shown below

[image: Screen shot of code]

As you can see it doesnt like `screen` so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I then looked into using Javascript but not sure how to trigger it without an event.  I have the following so far.

```
    <script>
    var screenWidth = screen.width;
    var screenHeight = screen.height;
    document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.UniqueID%>").innerText = screenWidth;
</script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" />
```

When i query this in my vb I just get an empty string.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you are running it server side, you'll get the server screen size...

Comment: ahh ok, well i definatley do not want that I want the users screen width

Comment: What you try to do, maybe is other solution.